# How can I fix a `LazyInitializationException`?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

My `User` & `Transfer` entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
// [...]
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Transfer> transfers;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "transfer")
public class Transfer {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", updatable=false)
private User user;
}
```

Where I get the `LazyInitializationException`:

```
public void transferToFriend(Requirement requirement) {

Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(requirement.getUserId());
if (optionalUser.isPresent() && !Objects.isNull(recipient)) { // LazyInitializationException
// [...] }
}
```

Console `LazyInitializationException`:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sample.model.User.transfers, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

What I've tried:

- `fetch="EAGER"`
- `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=false`

**EDIT**
I discovered that two `@Override` methods caused the issue in `User`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", ibanCode=" + ibanCode +
                ", bicCode=" + bicCode +
                ", balance=" + balance +
                ", friendsList='" + friendsList + '\'' +
                ", transfers=" + transfers +
                '}';
}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return ibanCode == user.ibanCode && bicCode == user.bicCode && Double.compare(user.balance, balance) == 0 && Objects.equals(id, user.id) && Objects.equals(email, user.email) && Objects.equals(password, user.password) && Objects.equals(firstName, user.firstName) && Objects.equals(lastName, user.lastName) && Objects.equals(friendsList, user.friendsList) && Objects.equals(transfers, user.transfers);
    }
```

Those are needed in my `Spring Boot` unit tests. How should I fix it?

Comment: Annotate the `transferToFriend` method with @Transactional.  As an aside, re-consider your equals method: should 2 user objects with the same immutable id be considered equal regardles of the rest of properties?

Answer (score 0):

The default for the `@OneToMany` annotation is `FetchType.LAZY` so your collections are loaded lazily.

In order to be able to access the collection after you've retrieved the object you need to be in a transactional context (you need an open session)

When you call:

```
Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findById(requirement.getUserId());
```

internally a new session is created, the object is retrieved and as soon as the `findById` method returns the session is closed.

What you should do is make sure you have an open session whenever you access the lazy collection in your User object (which both the `equals` method and `toString` do).

The simplest way is to annotate the `transferToFriend` method with `@Transactional` and make sure you call the method from outside your service otherwise (because of the way AOP proxies are handled) no transaction will be created (hence no session).